# laravel get error trace of 500 response

Tags: laravel, exception, middleware

I have a middleware that automatically logs all incoming requests. It also sends me an email when the status is 500. However, `$response->getContent(`) only returns "Server Error" when debugging mode is disabled.

Is there some way to get more detailed information about the cause, like

```
$exception->getMessage() vs. $exception->getTraceAsString()
```

are available for the Exception class

current code:

```
 if($response->getStatusCode() == 500) {
            ErrorHandler::sendEmail('Incoming Request Error 500', $response->getContent());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can interrogate the exception in the ExceptionHandler class before reporting and rendering take place: [Source Line 37](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/3e43e6b1d04793c3837ad383f54aae062c085fd8/app/Exceptions/Handler.php#L37).

For example:

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    logger($exception->getMessage());
    parent::report($exception);
}
```